# Why is it possible to index an object that has type never?

Tags: typescript

With `strict` enabled in `tsconfig.json`, why does `tsc` not issue an error when indexing an object of type `never`?

```
const mystery = ({ foo: 1 } as never)

console.log(mystery['foo'])  // no error
console.log(mystery.foo)  // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'never'.

export {}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgT2gUwE4JgXhgCgN4wBmIIAXDAIwwC+MAhhDGMgG5oCUAUJ6JCADbIAdPxABzHIhToA2gHJiIOQF12MGAHoNTEDDSoQqHuAgDhoiVKhoEQxWs3aACgYAOaKBgUk5MACYgyIxgILDIAB4AltAw4DCe7jByzGyockLcEa6GsHjUnEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's bug #41021](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41021):

> **'never' (and probably 'void') shouldn't be silently indexable types**
>
> DanielRosenwasser commented on Oct 10, 2020
>
> ```
> let x = [1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(x => { console.log(x));
> x["hello"] = 123;
> ```
>
> Expected: an error that x is possibly void or something
> Actual: no errors
>
> ---
>
> DanielRosenwasser commented on Oct 10, 2020
>
> Actually, `never` seems to suffer from the same issue..

The TypeScript team are actively fixing it, but no fix is available yet.

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4FsCeBnZIYYC54A7EANzwG4AoasAe2K3qQDoJ6BzACkxzwwBtAEQAzevWEBdAJSV4C%20AHol8AHL14eGPRh1GzNhx59c%20VuPpzFNlfAAKOgA55kGeAHJLH%20MHogsEnpUEAAPAEsceEZ4NxdPUgoYD1YgA) a simpler replication:

```typescript
declare let mystery: never;

console.log(mystery["foo"]);    // No error
console.log(mystery.foo);       // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'never'.
```